# How to make a carousel page with common header and footer in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using portable Xamarin.Forms (cross platform) having Android and IOS project.

I am using carousel page so that I can swipe page.

I want only middle content should swipe not whole page. header and footer should not be swipe

You can see in below image that whole page is swiping. I want only middle content to swipe

[image]

Please suggest me how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use listview with horizontal swipe instead of coursal page. it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You should look at pre-release version of `Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView` for your use-case:

```
Nuget: `Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView 2.3.0-pre2`
```

`CarouselView` is a replacement for the `CarouselPage`. and `CarouselPage` will be marked as deprecated sometime in a future release of `Xamarin.Forms`.

`CarouselView`'s are virtualized, a huge memory decrease over `CarouselPage` when dealing with more than a couple of pages and can be used like a "control" within a `Page` those you can apply header/footer templates to your page and place the `CarouselView` in the center.

Source: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView

Comment: Thanks for it. but I am using xamarin version 2.0.0.6482. if i update xamarin then lots of error are occurring like  

- "No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'" 

- "C:\Program Files \MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(290,2): error XA5209: Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r14.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v13\22.1.1\content directory" 

54 error occur. plz give me another solution

Comment: Those errors can be fixed via cleaning and rebuilding your project so the Android resources are rebuilt. Other then that you can look at using templates to add common elements to each page

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively straightforward refactor using ControlTemplates:

[Xamarin.Forms control templates](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/control-templates/creating/)

Presuming you are using MVVM, you would then assign the ControlTemplate to the ContentPage controlTemplate property: e.g.

```
contentView.ControlTemplate = new SampleControlTemplate()
```

I personally use GridViews within the ControlTemplate to get a more finite control of the layout. The final output is the area defined as the ContentPresenter will be populated with the layout from your ContentPage (in your case the CarouselPage).